# Problems with a TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here my problem, I define all the commands in this code in order to have a kind of prespective and to see the circle as in a 3d space (with the dashed part to be in the back. My problem is that also if I change the angle of elevation nothing happens to the circle. Someone could see any error that I made?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shapes,positioning,fit,arrows,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(0,0)}}}
}
\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);
  \draw[current plane,dashed] (\angVis-180:1) arc (\angVis-180:\angVis:1);
}
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis-180:1);
  \draw[current plane,dashed] (180-\angVis:1) arc (180-\angVis:\angVis:1);
}

%% document-wide tikz options and styles

\tikzset{%
  >=latex, % option for nice arrows
  inner sep=0pt,%
  outer sep=2pt,%
  mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,
    fill=black,circle}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]
  \def\R{0.5}
  \def\angEl{-30}
  \foreach \t in {0} { \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{\t} }
  %\draw[dashed] (0,.5) arc (0:180: .5 and .25);
  %\draw (0,.5) arc (180:360: .5 and .25);
  \draw (-1,-3) ellipse (.5 and .25);
  \draw (1,-3) ellipse (.5 and .25);
  \draw (-.5,0) to[out=-90,in=90] (-1.5,-3);
  \draw (.5,0) to[out=-90,in=90] (1.5,-3);
  \draw (-.5,-3) to[out=90,in=180] (0,-2);
  \draw (0,-2) to[out=0,in=90] (.5,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces - on my computer - the following result,

[image]

**Note** that probably I included more packages than necessary, since alla of this is part of a bigger document. I use TeX distribution 2014 on a mac. I say this since I recompiled this file recently after an update from 2013 to 2014 distribution, and before the update all worked fine.

Comment: Are you aware of `tqft` package of our Andrew Stacey just for these diagrams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an error you made. The problem with your code is that it is using the `estyle` (internally using `\edef`) syntax. Most probably you got your code some time ago when `estyle` had a different implementation. To recover the desired behaviour simply change `estyle` to `style` in the definitions of `\LongitudePlane` and `\LatitudePlane`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shapes,positioning,fit,arrows,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth
  \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(0,0)}}}
}
\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);
  \draw[current plane,dashed] (\angVis-180:1) arc (\angVis-180:\angVis:1);
}
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis-180:1);
  \draw[current plane,dashed] (180-\angVis:1) arc (180-\angVis:\angVis:1);
}

%% document-wide tikz options and styles

\tikzset{%
  >=latex, % option for nice arrows
  inner sep=0pt,%
  outer sep=2pt,%
  mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,
    fill=black,circle}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]
  \def\R{0.5}
  \def\angEl{-30}
  \foreach \t in {0} { \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{\t} }
  %\draw[dashed] (0,.5) arc (0:180: .5 and .25);
  %\draw (0,.5) arc (180:360: .5 and .25);
  \draw (-1,-3) ellipse (.5 and .25);
  \draw (1,-3) ellipse (.5 and .25);
  \draw (-.5,0) to[out=-90,in=90] (-1.5,-3);
  \draw (.5,0) to[out=-90,in=90] (1.5,-3);
  \draw (-.5,-3) to[out=90,in=180] (0,-2);
  \draw (0,-2) to[out=0,in=90] (.5,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, using a loop with just one iteration seems an overkill. Instead of

```
\foreach \t in {0} { \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{\t} }
```

you can simply say

```
\DrawLatitudeCircle[\R]{0}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have already got the message by percusse regarding `tqft` library by Andrew Stacey. Here is a sample.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{tqft}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tqft/cobordism/.style={draw},tqft/every lower boundary component/.style={draw,dashed}, every tqft/.append style={transform shape } ]
  \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
    \pic [tqft/pair of pants];
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, I am still curios: how could be that my code does not work anymore? have you tried to compile it on you machine? Does it give the same result? Thanks